# R - Mean always returns 0

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, mean, rbind

My goal is to create a function that reads specified .csv files (all of which have the same format) from the working directory, bind them into one data frame, and then return the mean of a specified column ("nitrate" or "sulfate") of that data frame. The current problem is that every time I call the function *no matter how many files I chose to read/how many rows the mean is calculated on,* the function always returns 0. I'm not quite sure how to fix this, any help appreciated.

```
pollutantmean <- function(pollutant, id = 1:332, directory = 
                            "/Users/marsh/datasciencecoursera/specdata/") {
  setwd(directory)
  list <- list.files()
  df <- data.frame()
  for(i in id) {
        x <- read.csv(list[i])
        df <- rbind(df,x)
  }
  mean(!is.na(df["pollutant",]))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the mean and there are `NA`'s present in your data use: `mean(df["pollutant",], na.rm = TRUE)`

You are calculating the ratio of how many `NA`'s are present. If you get 0 back, it means that you have only `NA`'s . So maybe there is something else wrong as well. Maybe you can use `dput()` on a dataframe so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong.  It should be

```
mean(!is.na(df[[pollutant]]))
```

We don't need quotes for `pollutant` and should be same as the input argument.  Secondly, the `,` implies that we are selecting the row names as the general format for indexing is `row, column`, which can be either `numeric` or `character` strings.  In this case, we need to calculate the `mean` of missing values for a specific column.  So `[[` will extract the column or we can do

```
mean(!is.na(df[,pollutant]))
```

The whole function should now be

```
pollutantmean <- function(pollutant, id = 1:332, directory = 
                        "/Users/marsh/datasciencecoursera/specdata/") {
  setwd(directory)
  list <- list.files()
  df <- data.frame()
  for(i in id) {
     x <- read.csv(list[i])
     df <- rbind(df,x)
   }
  mean(!is.na(df[[pollutant]]))
}
```

This can also be optimized using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
pollutantmean <- function(pollutant, id = 1:332, directory = 
                        "/Users/marsh/datasciencecoursera/specdata/") {
  setwd(directory)
  lst <- list.files()
  df <- rbindlist(lapply(lst, fread))
   mean(!is.na(df[[pollutant]]))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, because there is no data to confirm this, but it looks like you are asking for the mean of the rows labeled pollutant, not the columns.

Typically a variable is saved in a column and individual observations are saved in rows. So, moving that comma will help get the right data into your calculation, giving you all `rows(observations)` of the `column="pollutant"`.

```
#how the data frame is constructed df[rows, columns]
```

By asking the way that you did, you got all of the observations that do not have an NA  in that row but you took the mean of the entire data frame.

```
pollutantmean <- function(pollutant, id = 1:332, directory = 
                            "/Users/marsh/datasciencecoursera/specdata/") {
      setwd(directory)
      list <- list.files()
      df <- data.frame()
      for(i in id) {
            x <- read.csv(list[i])
            df <- rbind(df,x)
      }

      mean(df[,pollutant], rm.na=TRUE)
    }
```

this says take the mean of all observations in the dataframe `df` column `pollutant` that are not = to NA this should give you what you want

Comment: not sure what you are talking about akrun...I copied the original post and edited it then noticed two grammar errors which I fixed  but your post came in while I was writing, I never saw it until I got this note and went to look at it...and it is not so original an idea that  two people would not get to it at the same time...and the final answer is different...data frame structure is pretty common error in the beginning.

Comment: okay, no problem. I noticed earlier that it was `"pollutant"` in your post

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers helped me fix it.

```
 mean(df[[pollutant]], na.rm = TRUE)
```

ended up returning the correct answers. Thanks!